# Copy blob between storage accounts

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to copy a blob from one storage account to another (In a different location).

I'm using the following code:

```
var sourceContainer = sourceClient.GetContainerReference(containerId);
var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
if (await sourceBlob.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    var targetContainer = targetClient.GetContainerReference(containerId);
    await targetContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
    await targetBlob.DeleteIfExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

and I get a "Not Found" error.
I do get that the source blob indeed exists.
Am I using the wrong command? Is there something I'm missing regarding copying between storage accounts?

Comment: Please provide the full Error message

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. --- The specified resource does not exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After playing around with the code, I reached an answer.
Copying between storage accounts can only be achieved when the source blob is a uri and not a blob reference.
The following code worked:

```
var sourceContainer = sourceClient.GetContainerReference(containerId);
var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
// Create a policy for reading the blob.
var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
};
// Get SAS of that policy.
var sourceBlobToken = sourceBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
// Make a full uri with the sas for the blob.
var sourceBlobSAS = string.Format("{0}{1}", sourceBlob.Uri, sourceBlobToken);
var targetContainer = targetClient.GetContainerReference(containerId);
await targetContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
await targetBlob.DeleteIfExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(sourceBlobSAS)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Another option is to use the Azure Storage Data Movement Library for .NET. This is the library that underlies AzCopy.

Take a look at the announcement here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-0-2-0/

There's also a helpful sample application here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/tree/master/samples/DataMovementSamples

(If you're not familiar with AzCopy, see here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/)

Comment: @TamraMyers-Microsoft Is it more efficient than using the standard Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library? Or are they both legit?

Comment: For StartCopyAsync which is used in your code, DataMovement Library isn't more efficient since it's server side copy.However, for downloading, uploading, or sync copy between blobs (download to memory then upload), AzCopy and DataMovement Library are much more efficient than Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library since it's doing the transfer in multiple threads.

Answer (score 10):

You can also copy blobs between storage accounts by using streams:

```
var sourceContainer = sourceClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainer);
var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobId);
var targetContainer = targetClient.GetContainerReference(destContainer);
var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destBlobId);

using (var targetBlobStream = await targetBlob.OpenWriteAsync())
{
    using (var sourceBlobStream = await sourceBlob.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        await sourceBlobStream.CopyToAsync(targetBlobStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice clean solution. Worked for me.