# Copy file from one Azure storage account to another

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy a file from one storage account to another account using [`StartCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-dotnet) method to copy the file. Check the below code.

```
CloudStorageAccount sourceStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"source storage account connection string");
CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"destination storage account connection string");

CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobClient destBlobClient = destStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var sourceContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("sourceContainer");
var destContainer = destBlobClient.GetContainerReference("destContainer");

CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");

targetBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
```

But it always return the following error.

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

What am I missing here ?

Note, the same code works perfectly if I try to copy files from one container to another within **same** storage account.

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599777/copy-blob-between-storage-accounts?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example on how a copy should be performed (taken from [Introducing Asynchronous Cross-Account Copy Blob](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob/)):

```
public static void CopyBlobs(
            CloudBlobContainer srcContainer,  
            string policyId, 
            CloudBlobContainer destContainer)
{
    // get the SAS token to use for all blobs
    string blobToken = srcContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(
                   new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(), policyId);


    var srcBlobList = srcContainer.ListBlobs(true, BlobListingDetails.None);
    foreach (var src in srcBlobList)
    {
        var srcBlob = src as CloudBlob;

        // Create appropriate destination blob type to match the source blob
        CloudBlob destBlob;
        if (srcBlob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.BlockBlob)
        {
            destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            destBlob = destContainer.GetPageBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
        }

        // copy using src blob as SAS
        destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this using `TransferManager.CopyAsync` Method

```
CloudStorageAccount sourceStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"source storage account connection string");
CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"destination storage account connection string");

CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobClient destBlobClient = destStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var sourceContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("sourceContainer");
var destContainer = destBlobClient.GetContainerReference("destContainer");

CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");

TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, targetBlob, true).Wait();
```

`TransferManager` is under the namespace `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement`. To get the reference install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement` in nuget manager.

Answer (score 0):

i recently ran into this error trying to copy from /uploads to /raw within a single blob account.

The issue was that the container /raw didn't exist on the destination side within the test environment.

(ie, this error is actually thrown by the destination, not the source)